# Moving folders based on condition

Tags: command-line, powershell, filesystems, powershell-ise

I have many excel files in a single folder like below.

```
+----------------------+
| 01012019_LOC001.xlsx |
| 01012019_LOC002.xlsx |
| 01012019_LOC003.xlsx |
| 02012019_LOC001.xlsx |
| 02012019_LOC002.xlsx |
| 02012019_LOC003.xlsx |
| 03012019_LOC001.xlsx |
| 03012019_LOC002.xlsx |
| 03012019_LOC003.xlsx |
+----------------------+
```

a date plus Location combination structure `DDMMYYYY_LOCXXX`

I want to move these files to it's respective folders created similar to the below structure.

```
MAIN_FOLDER
|
|-LOC001
  |-01012019
  |-02012019
  |-03012019
  |
|-LOC002
  |-01012019
  |-02012019
  |-03012019
  |
|-LOC003
  |-01012019
  |-02012019
  |-03012019
|
```

I can transfer one at a time with `for /r %d in (01012019_LOC001.xlsx) do move "%d" "C:MAIN_FOLDER\LOC001\01012019\"`.

But I'm looking for a more dynamic solution. Hence, please guide me to find a solution.

P.S.Note:- even a powershell answer would suffice.

Comment: For this you'll want to loop through the files with delayed expansion; the tricky part is splitting the filename up, though if the date string and loc string are set numbers of characters, you can cheese it with variable substrings. I'll type of an answer if I have a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll want to loop through the files with delayed expansion. Unless there are subfolders you also want to pull from, I would avoid the `/r` flag of `for` since it's recursive. The main issue is splitting the filename up since each half is a separate piece of information. It'll look something like this:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Excel\File\Directory"
set "des=C:\MAIN_FOLDER"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (%dir%\*.xlsx) do (
    set "file=%%~nA"
    if not exist "%des%\!file:~-6!" md "%des%\!file:~-6!"
    if not exist "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!.xlsx" move /y "%dir%\%%~nxA" "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!.xlsx"
)
```

This is a batch solution, so you can just copy and paste it into Notepad then save it as a `.bat` instead of a `.txt`.

First, I've set variables for `dir` (directory; where your Excel files are currently located) and `des` (destination; where you want to create your folders and move your files) - you'll need to edit those values to reflect your environment. Prior to doing anything else, we use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` since we are working with variables that change values every loop iteration. The `for` will loop through all excel files in the top-folder of our directory and assign them to parameter `%%A`; once inside the loop we set a variable called `file` as `%%~nA` which is just parameter `%%A` reduced to its filename only. We use one `if` statement to check to see if the folder for that file already exists - if it doesn't we make the folder with `md`, then we use another `if` statement to see if the file we're currently looking at already exists in the folder we just verified/made - if it doesn't, we move the file to the folder with `move` and suppress the confirmation prompt with `/y` (the `/y` isn't really necessary since we kick it off with an `if` statement, but it's best practice imo). The move command has a rename built into it, so we just use that to follow the naming scheme you wanted.

The cheesy part here are the variable substrings - since your dates and locations are set numbers of characters, we just count those characters and extract them as needed:
`!file:~-6!` just grabs the last six characters (our LOC information) while `!file:~0,8!` grabs the first eight characters (our date information). The only other thing worth noting is to use exclamation points within a loop that is using delayed expansion (since those are the variables that are changing); for our static variables (`dir` and `des`) the percent signs are fine throughout.

Hopefully this does what you wanted or at least gets you on the right track.

Reference: [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [variable substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), [move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)

Comment: The code ran successfully without any error. but.the files are not moved. let me check further & let you know. Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: ahh I think I see what I did - I left off the file extensions in the second `if` statement; it should be `if not exist "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!.xlsx" move /y "%dir%\%%~nxA" "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!.xlsx"`. I've updated the answer - let me know if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Yes. And I need to retain the original file name. Hence, I used `if not exist "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!.xml" move /y "%dir%\%%~nxA" "%des%\!file:~-6!\!file:~0,8!\%%~nA.xlsx"` with a small tweak at the end to get the exact output.  Also I saved the `.bat` file in `ANSI` format. earlier I saved in `UTF-8` which threw an error. Thank you for the awesome answer

Comment: no problem - glad you could make it work for you!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's a **PowerShell** version:

```
$Source = 'C:\Source'
$Dest   = 'C:\Destination'

Get-ChildItem $source -filter *.xls | foreach{
   $FolderName = $_.Basename.Split('_')[1]
   If (!(Test-Path "$Dest\$FolderName")) {
      New-Item -Path $Dest -Name $FolderName -ItemType Directory | out-null
   }
   Move-Item $_.FullName "$Dest\$FolderName"
}
```

I opted to get the **Loc###** string by splitting the basename on the underscore, which by itself returns a two-element string array. The **[1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)** subscript references the second element.
If **Test-Path** fails, we create the folder, piping the return to **out-null** to avoid screen display. Then **Move-Item** does just what it sounds like! :)

[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6)

[String.Split Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

[Test-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6)

[New-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6)

[Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thank you. works like a charm. I don't have much reputations to upvote your answer.